# How to show blank instead of column value for all duplicated columns of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

There is a similar question which answer this for a known number of columns and only a single selection column. But the problem here is that
I have no knowledge of columns (count, type) of a specified SQL query and also I want to blank for all columns not a single column.

For example lets say I have following query.

```
Select * from View1
```

Result :

```
Column(1)       Column(2)         Column(..)         Column(N)
1               A                 Sales              1500
2               C                 Sales              2500
3               C                 Sales              2500
4               A                 Development        2500
```

Expected result :

```
Column(1)       Column(2)         Column(..)         Column(N)
1               A                 Sales              1500
2               C                                    2500
3                                                        
4               A                 Development
```

Pseudo SQL Query :

```
EXEC proc_blank_query_result 'Select * from View1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can do this with lag, something like this:

```
select
  nullif(column1, lag(column1) over (order by yourorderbyclause)) as column1,
  nullif(column2, lag(column2) over (order by yourorderbyclause)) as column2,
  ...
from
  View1
```

To make it dynamic, well then you have to parse a lot of metadata from the query. Using [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx) might be a good idea, or use `select into` a temp. table and parse the columns of it.